# How to add jquery-jtable in php page?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am new in jtable, I am retrieving "name","sex" field from mysql database. How to display records using jquery jtable. Please be specific.

```
<?php 

 <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$sql="select name,sex from user";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: What does the documentation and examples tell you? If jTable.org: http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted

Comment: You need to output the php values into json format and then append them into the table .. see http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted#ListAction